# "Пусть куда" - где-нибудь так говорят?

Tags: грамотная-речь, диалектизмы

Мне важно сохранить живой авторскую индивидуальность. Если возможно. А не как лучше.

> И не раз по дороге в отель мне хотелось махнуть рукой на очередной
>   тягучий вечер, подойти к пограничному контролю, протянуть свой паспорт
>   и отправиться по мутной реке, пожалуйста, только немедленно и пусть
>   куда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне известны только выражения "(можно) **хоть куда**" и "**хоть куда-нибудь** (да ехать)". Первое, более короткое, по смыслу немного отличается - его вроде как не присоединить союзом "и" (из-за укороченности; хочется добавить тире перед "и"), а второе - можно (оно сильнее связывается с упомянутым "отправлением").

Answer (score 2):

И не раз по дороге в отель мне хотелось махнуть рукой на очередной тягучий вечер, подойти к пограничному контролю, протянуть свой паспорт и отправиться по мутной реке — пожалуйста, только немедленно и пусть хоть куда.

Comment: Спасибо. Это я живой текст редактирую, вопросы-ответы отправляю автору: ЛОшку он вручает.

Comment: Да, интересный автор. Стиль оригинальный, очень образный, живописный, все определения на месте. И язык  тоже хорош: легкий, разговорный, эмоциональный.

Comment: Шаронушка, автор шлёт тебе личную благодарность за все разъяснения. "Так что безмерно благодарна Sharon, которая даже в одном предложении ловит суть, и контекст, и попытку. Спасибо!"; "И снова признательна Шарон – за добрые слова, вот ради такого понимания и работаешь!"

Comment: Большое спасибо автору, который дает нам возможность  вместе с ним увидеть прекрасный и разнообразный мир природы и искусства, побывать в разных городах, услышать живые голоса людей. В наше время можно прочитать всё и обо всём, но информационный текст, конечно же, никогда не сравнится с художественным словом.

Comment: Переслано автору. А то её все кусают...

Comment: Наверное, это не должно удивлять. Всё самобытное, талантливое, оригинальное воспринимается публикой неоднозначно и обычно подвергается гонениям. Вероятно, лучшая защита в данном случае - это безупречность формы.

Comment: Автор пишет (воспроизвожу как есть): "как же мне тепло и счастливо! только того и хотелось! знаю - всем нам даруют. разное. вот я например писать не умею. правильно, но как бы хотелось поделиться тем, что вижу! да равзе за моей межбуквицей разобрал бы кто? спасибо!!!"

Comment: Классно! А к Вашему труду, Галина,  я теперь прониклась еще большим уважением. Вы как бы не просто редактор, а почти соавтор.